# Error- taking address of temporary -fpermissive C++

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <set>

using namespace std;

void leerConjunto(set<int> *, int);

void imprimirConjunto(set<int> *);

set<int> opUnion(set<int> *, set<int> *);

set<int> opInterseccion(set<int> *, set<int> *);

set<int> opDiferencia(set<int> *, set<int> *);

int main() {
set<int> a, b;
int aux;

cout << "Cuantos elementos son en el conjunto A: ";
cin >> aux;

leerConjunto(&a, aux);

cout << endl << "Cuantos elementos son en el conjunto B: ";
cin >> aux;

leerConjunto(&b, aux);

cout << endl << "Conjunto A:";
imprimirConjunto(&a);

cout << "Conjunto B:";
imprimirConjunto(&b);

cout << "A union B:";
imprimirConjunto(&opUnion(&a, &b));

cout << "A interseccion B:";
imprimirConjunto(&opInterseccion(&a, &b));

cout << "A - B:";
imprimirConjunto(&opDiferencia(&a, &b));

cout << "B - A:";
imprimirConjunto(&opDiferencia(&b, &a));

return 0;
}

void leerConjunto(set<int> *conj, int cantidad) {
for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i) {
int elemento;
cout << "Escribe un elemento: ";
cin >> elemento;
conj->insert(elemento);
}
}

void imprimirConjunto(set<int> *conj) {
set<int>::iterator it;

for (it = conj->begin(); it != conj->end(); it++) {
cout << " " << *it;
}

cout << endl;
}

set<int> opUnion(set<int> *a, set<int> *b) {
set<int> unionSet;
set<int>::iterator it;

for (it = a->begin(); it != a->end(); it++) {
unionSet.insert(*it);
}

for (it = b->begin(); it != b->end(); it++) {
if (unionSet.count(*it) == 0) {
unionSet.insert(*it);
}
}

return unionSet;
}

set<int> opInterseccion(set<int> *a, set<int> *b) {
set<int> interseccion;
set<int> *mayor, *menor;
set<int>::iterator it;

if (a->size() > b->size()) {
mayor = a;
menor = b;
} else {
mayor = b;
menor = a;
}

for (it = menor->begin(); it != menor->end(); it++) {
if (mayor->count(*it) > 0) {
interseccion.insert(*it);
}
}

return interseccion;
}

set<int> opDiferencia(set<int> *a, set<int> *b) {
set<int> diferencia;
set<int>::iterator it;

for (it = a->begin(); it != a->end(); it++) {
if (b->count(*it) == 0) {
diferencia.insert(*it);
}
}

return diferencia;
}
```

AL MOMENTO DE COMPILAR ME DA ERROR EN `imprimirConjunto(&opUnion(&a, &b));`
Y LAS DEMÁS

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos devueltos por una función son elementos temporales. Si no se almacenan en una variable estos valores se pierden al momento.

Lo que está sucediendo es que el objeto devuelto por `opUnion` no lo estás almacenando en ninguna variable. En vez de eso coges su referencia y se la pasas a otra función. Como el objeto es temporal, antes de ejecutar la función `imprimirConjunto` el programa destruye el objeto temporal. Al final el puntero que le llega a la función no es válido porque apunta a un objeto que ya no existe.

Para que tu programa funcione tienes varias alternativas. La más sencilla es almacenar los objetos retornados en variables:

```
set<int> temporal = opUnion(&a,&b);
imprimirConjunto(temporal);
```

También puedes optar por evitar el uso de punteros. De esta forma se hará una copia del objeto temporal y será esa copia la que se utilice dentro de `imprimirConjunto`:

```
void imprimirConjunto(set<int>);
```